# ajax -- add comments asynchronously

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two php files that handle a commenting system I have created for my website. On the index.php I have my form and an echo statement that prints out the user input from my database. I have another file called insert.php that actually takes in the user input and inserts that into my database before it is printed out.

My index.php basically looks like this

```
<form id="comment_form" action="insertCSAir.php" method="GET">
    Comments:
    <input type="text" class="text_cmt" name="field1_name" id="field1_name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='0'/>
</form>

<!--connects to database and queries to print out on site-->
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'name', '', 'comment_schema');
    $query="SELECT COMMENTS FROM csAirComment";
    $results = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        echo '<div class="comment" >';
        $output= $row["COMMENTS"];
        //protects against cross site scripting
        echo htmlspecialchars($output ,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
       echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

I want users to be able to write comments and have it updated without reloading the page (which is why I will be using AJAX). This is the code I have added to the head tag

```
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        // this is the id of the form
        $("#comment_form").submit(function(e) {

        var url = "insert.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: $("#comment_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data); // show response from the php script.
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
      });
   </script>
```

However, nothing is happening. The alert() doesn't actually do anything and I'm not exactly sure how to make it so that when the user comments, it gets added to my comments in order (it should be appending down the page). I think that the code I added is the basic of what needs to happen, but not even the alert is working. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is basically insert.php

```
if(!empty($_GET["field1_name"])) {

    //protects against SQL injection
    $field1_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET["field1_name"]);
    $field1_name_array = explode(" ",$field1_name);

    foreach($field1_name_array as $element){
        $query = "SELECT replaceWord FROM changeWord WHERE badWord = '" . $element . "' ";
        $query_link = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_link)>0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_link);
            $goodWord = $row['replaceWord'];
            $element= $goodWord;
        }
        $newComment = $newComment." ".$element;
     }

     //Escape user inputs for security
     $sql = "INSERT INTO parentComment (COMMENTS) VALUES ('$newComment')";
     $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
     //attempt insert query execution

     header("Location:index.php");
     die();

     mysqli_close($link);
}
else{
    die('comment is not set or not containing valid value');
```

it also filters out bad words which is why there's an if statement check for that.

Comment: Any console error? Also, did you try to load the insert.php (even without values) directly in your browser's address bar to check that it's loading?

Comment: What does `insert.php` look like? By the way, you should switch to POST for your database inserts, both in your ajax call and you regular script.

Comment: Post insert.php code please

Comment: There aren't any console errors. The reason I used get was because POST was always returning an empty array and was giving me errors before. GET was the only way I was able to retrieve information from the user. Also I have updated with the insert.php code

Comment: Why do you have a redirect header for a script that may be called only by an ajax request ?

Comment: Don't do a header redirect, `echo` out what you want to display.

Comment: Part of your problem is that when your index.php script is successful, it immediately issues a header and dies without a message. If a php script ends without echoing content, the ajax gets nothing to display. You'll need to add a line of code to differentiate ajax requests from others and then echo content / issue a header based on the context, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: are you referring to the header("Location:...")? Sorry that should say index.php.I'll change that. I did that because I wanted the page to reload onto the same page as where the user puts in the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET["field1_name"])) {

//protects against SQL injection
    $field1_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET["field1_name"]);
    $field1_name_array = explode(" ",$field1_name);

    foreach($field1_name_array as $element)
    {
        $query = "SELECT replaceWord FROM changeWord WHERE badWord = '" . $element . "' ";
        $query_link = mysqli_query($link,$query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_link)>0)
        {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_link);
            $goodWord = $row['replaceWord'];
            $element= $goodWord;
        }
        $newComment = $newComment." ".$element;
    }

//Escape user inputs for security
    $sql = "INSERT INTO parentComment (COMMENTS) VALUES ('$newComment')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
//attempt insert query execution
    if ($result)
    {
        http_response_code(200); //OK
        //you may want to send it in json-format. its up to you
        $json = [
            'commment' => $newComment
        ];

        print_r( json_encode($json) );
        exit();
    }


//header("Location:chess.php");   don't know why you would do that in an ajax-accessed file
//die();

mysqli_close($link);
}
else{
    die('comment is not set or not containing valid value');
}


?>

<script>
        // this is the id of the form
        $("#comment_form").submit(function(e) {

        var url = "insert.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", //Id recommend "post"
            url: url,
            dataType: json,
            data: $("#comment_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                $('#myElement').append( data.comment );
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
      });
   </script>
```

To get a response from "insert.php" you actually need to print/echo the content you want to handle in the "success()" from the ajax-request.

Also you want to set the response-code to 200 to make sure "success: function(data)" will be called. Otherwise you might end up in "error: function(data)".

Comment: so that #myElement, what is that referring to exactly? Also, I have a echo in my while loop in the index.php that echo's out the comments, does that mean instead of writing it in there I'd write it in the success() function?

Comment: @Oviya Arasu - Its refering to whatever element you want to put the comment-text inside.
you could do `$('body').append(data.comment);` which would just append the comment-text at the end of the body (website)